# I want to make my alert box more stylish and customized.how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
   function setValue(obj,path)
{
    var expected_path="<%= session.getAttribute("expected_path") %>";
    alert("expected_path"+expected_path);
    var path=path;

    if ((expected_path != "null" || expected_path != null) && path != expected_path)
      {
        alert("Error:- Attached Object is not from the expected path,Please commit the object in correct path and map again");
        alert("Expected_path  >>  " +expected_path);
      }
    else
        {
        window.opener.setFileAndRevisionProperties(obj);
        window.close();
        }
}
```

I want to make my alert box more stylish and customized. how to do it?.

Comment: "more stylish and customized" is not a problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how alert boxes differ in appearance from browser to browser? That's because it's a system object. You can't style it. You would need to create your own HTML element and duplicate the functionality of alert.